# File Access Permission

Tags: php, security, uploading

I need to upload a file to site with PHP code. How to set permission for upload folder if I want to users cant access to file by URL but PHP code read this file ?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which web server? (Lighttpd and Apache tips won't be much use if you're running IIS)

Answer (score 1):

If possible best way to do that is to put your uploaded files outside of your webroot. That way the files won't be accessible by url but your scripts can still access them.

Answer (score 0):

The `www` (or whatever account is used to run your web server) account needs to have write access to the directory. I would assume that you could block direct access to said directory through an `.htaccess` file placed in that directory.

It might look something like:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod 750` on the directory, which will give you full access, the server/program read + execute access, and users no access.